# I can't join multiple tables on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I need to join four tables into one on some conditions, but I only manage to join three of them, even if I do everything exactly the same on the fourth one. Can somebody, please, help me with this issue? It works if I delete the last paragraph, but if I leave it there it says "syntax error in JOIN operation".

```
SELECT Leidinys, ISSN, Pobudis

FROM ((Leidinio_ID_Leidinys 
       LEFT JOIN (Leidinio_ID_ISSN_ID 
                  LEFT JOIN ISSN_ID_ISSN 
                         ON  Leidinio_ID_ISSN_ID.ISSN_ID = ISSN_ID_ISSN.ISSN_ID) 
              ON (Leidinio_ID_Leidinys.Leidinio_ID = Leidinio_ID_ISSN_ID.Leidinio_ID))

LEFT JOIN ((Leidinio_ID_Pobudzio_ID 
            LEFT JOIN  Pobudzio_ID_Pobudis 
                   ON Leidinio_ID_Pobudzio_ID.Pobudzio_ID = Pobudzio_ID_Pobudis.Pobudzio_ID)) 
       ON (Leidinio_ID_Leidinys.Leidinio_ID = Leidinio_ID_Pobudzio_ID.Leidinio_ID))

LEFT JOIN ((Leidinio_ID_Metai_ID 
            LEFT JOIN  Metai_ID_Prieigos_Metai 
                   ON Leidinio_ID_Metai_ID.Metai_ID = Metai_ID_Prieigos_Metai.Metai_ID) 
           ON (Leidinio_ID_Leidinys.Leidinio_ID = Leidinio_ID_Metai_ID.Leidinio_ID))
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Or SQL Server? They're not the same thing.

Comment: Weirdest join ever I thought it was an ORM stuff at first.

Comment: If you format your code, you will probably find some extra parentheses that are causing the problem.  I'm not exactly sure why you are using the parentheses, they are not needed.

Comment: I dont think that this would depend on whether server i am using, because it works with three tables, but the magic happens with the fourth.. And parentheses are not the problem. I tried everything with them

Comment: http://codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html Do it like this and after the ON conditions add another JOIN etc.

Comment: Ancient syntax did not have `JOIN` keyword at all.

Comment: @user3195619 You think that this doesn't depend on the RDBMS, but why refuse to share it?, it helps to give you a better answer

Comment: @user3195619 Formatting counts when making complicated joins.  Also, old style joins are being phased out.  *= and =* do not work in SQL Server 2012!

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA op isn't using old style joins, s/he's just enclosing them strangely on parentheses. But no `*=` or `=*` there

Comment: Personally, I find nested `OUTER JOIN`s (of which `LEFT` is one) are usually unnecessary/unwanted - often, there actually **will** always be data (joining something named `<table_reference>_Id` to `<table_reference>` seems like a prime candidate).  They seem to make reasoning about results/existence of result rows difficult.

Answer (score 1):

your parens are out of sync i bet

you need the first parens after first FROM to enclose all 3 "left joins" clauses, so you need to
1) copy to clipboard then remove the last "left join clause"
2) insert the copied code in front of the very last parens

this is my best guess based on the info provided, good luck

Comment: My parents are out of sync? I think that's why they're divorced.

Comment: Alternatively, just remove the first opening parenthesis and the last closing parenthesis on the last line. However, I think it would worth mentioning that *no parenthesis at all* is actually necessary for this syntax to work in either MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: at least when it comes to views, mysql adds parens behind the scenes, so if you start by retrieving code from an existing view, you either need to work with them or take (waste?) the time to remove them (only to have mysql add them again once you apply the code that defines view)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. But hey, if it was a view definition and you removed all the brackets and updated the view, MySQL would at least add them back *correctly*, wouldn't it? No need to guess which one you or someone before you had messed up with – so, some solution too, in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but a pointer the table names are so similar to each other and also they r not in english so struggling a bit , but here is something you need to do .

JOIN between two table at one time and then mention their joining condition in ON clause

```
SELECT Leidinys, ISSN, Pobudis
FROM Leidinio_ID_Leidinys LEFT JOIN Leidinio_ID_ISSN_ID    --<-- Two Table in JOIN 
ON Leidinio_ID_Leidinys.Leidinio_ID = Leidinio_ID_ISSN_ID.Leidinio_ID  --<-- Condition on you want to join these table
LEFT JOIN ISSN_ID_ISSN                                 --<-- result set on 1st join, joins with this table
ON  Leidinio_ID_ISSN_ID.ISSN_ID = ISSN_ID_ISSN.ISSN_ID  --<-- condition on which you want to join the result set and this table ... and so on ....
LEFT JOIN Leidinio_ID_Pobudzio_ID 
ON Leidinio_ID_Leidinys.Leidinio_ID = Leidinio_ID_Pobudzio_ID.Leidinio_ID
LEFT JOIN  Pobudzio_ID_Pobudis 
ON Leidinio_ID_Pobudzio_ID.Pobudzio_ID = Pobudzio_ID_Pobudis.Pobudzio_ID
.
...... Join with other tables along with their joining conditions and so on.....
```

Then also in your Select statement you need to mention the TableName.Column name because the column names you have mentioned in your Select statement exists in more then One table you need to tell sql server from which table you need that particular column.